# O javascript executa a função sem que o botão seja clicado

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

**Objetivo**

Substituir o conteúdo do elemento  `<P>` por um novo texto ao clicar em um botão.

**Problema**

Sempre que a página carrega, o `javascript` executa a função e altera o texto sem que o botão seja clicado.

**Tentativa de solução**

Aloquei os `Id` em variáveis e criei uma função que incluiria o texto `hello world` no parágrafo, fora da função chamei a variável `btn` (botão) incluí o `onclick` e atribuí a função `mudaTexto`.

> HTML

```
<style>
  .lol{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
}
</style>

<button id="btn1">1</button>

<br><br>

<div class="lol">
  <p id="teste">hhh</p>
</div>
```

> JS

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
let texto = document.getElementById('teste');

function mudaTexto(){
texto.innerText = 'hello world';
}

btn.onClick = mudaTexto();
```

Agradeço a ajuda de antemão.

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título nem adicionar o código na pergunta (pois o mesmo já se encontra na resposta abaixo e é redundante colocá-lo aqui). Ao aceitar uma resposta  (clicando no ✔️) vc já indicou que o problema está resolvido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Na verdade, havia um erro de sintaxe. Corrigi, veja a demonstração abaixo:**

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn1');
let texto = document.getElementById('teste');

function mudaTexto(){
texto.innerText = 'hello world';
}
//Erro de sintaxe:
//btn.onClick = mudaTexto();

//Sintaxe correta:
btn.onclick = mudaTexto;
```

```html
<style>
  .lol{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
}
</style>

<button id="btn1">1</button>

<br><br>

<div class="lol">
  <p id="teste">hhh</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Erro de sintaxe **e** o fato de estar executando a função na atribuição. Não se trata somente de um erro.

Comment: Quando eu retiro os parênteses o código não funciona, já com os parênteses o javascript executa a função assim que carrega a page, o botão só funciona corretamente quando eu chamo a função diretamente na tag button, mas quero saber como executar no próprio código.

Comment: Você clicou no botão azul acima "Executar" e testou?

Comment: Agora percebi meu erro, escrevi "onClick" no lugar de "onclick". Agora funciona corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

Retire a chamada da função `btn.onClick = mudaTexto();` do código do script e atribua-o diretamente no botão, assim:

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="mudaTexto();">1</button>
```

Dessa forma você está adicionando o evento de clicar diretamente ao botão.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você não está atribuindo a função ao evento `onclick`, mas sim invocando a função. Além disso, há também um erro de digitação. Veja:

> ```
> btn.onClick = mudaTexto();
> ```

O que você precisa fazer é, mudar `onClick` para `onclick` e parar de executar a função durante a atribuição:

```
btn.onclick = mudaTexto;
```

Desse modo, você estará atribuindo a função ao *listener* do evento, e não o seu resultado, como estava sendo feito anteriormente.

Comment: Não vai dar certo. Não é onClick, mas sim onclick.

Comment: Erro de digitação... Obrigado! :)

Comment: Quando eu retiro os parênteses o código não funciona, já com os parênteses o javascript executa a função assim que carrega a page, o botão só funciona corretamente quando eu chamo a função diretamente na tag button, mas quero saber como executar no próprio código.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta com os códigos que foram passados aqui, se você quiser, podes colocar o que passei, para nós analisarmos melhor.